# "status": 400, "error": "Bad Request", the method does not work out Java REST

Tags: java, spring

[image]

Why the code doesn't work and how can I fix it

or you can somehow rewrite this method in a different way, I'm struggling for the second day I didn't find anything worthwhile on the Internet

Controller

```java
@PostMapping(value = "message/{id}",params = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Message createMessage(@RequestBody Message newMessage,  @PathVariable("id") Long id){
    return addMessage(newMessage,id);
}
private Message addMessage(Message message,Long id){
    return  messageRepository.save(new Message(message.getText(),userRepository.findById(id).get()));
}
```

Class

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String text;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;

    public Message(String text, User author) {
        this.text = text;
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your RestController has RequestMapping set to "/api" - if dont then your url should be "localhost:8080/message/1".

If this does not help:

- make sure the request hit method "createMessage" (for example set breakpoint in debug mode in this method and then try call it from postman) - if dont then make sure your annotations were imported from "org.springframework.web.bind.annotation".
- make sure your body from postman is correct Message class

By the way:

- Consider using DTO or Request classes to pass entity in/out your REST application - it will help you avoid circular reference in future and problems with de/serialization your entity.
- Consider using ResponseEntity instead of returning object to output - method with ResponseEntity should be like:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dgrQ.png)

Comment: Postman 
"message": "Parameter conditions \"application/json;charset=UTF-8\" not met for actual request parameters: ",
    "path": "/message/1"
what could this be related to

Comment: the annotation was imported correctly, but it does not get into the method

Comment: For what reason you specify "params = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE" (BTW its Deprecated) ?
If You specified it, I assume your request in postman has set Header "ContentType" to "application/json;charset=UTF-8" ?

Comment: Thanks figured out the problem was in  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE